# Props not updated when set from router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, watch

When I set a component props in the route definition the watcher doesn't work and the view is never updated.

#### In this example the update works correctly :

```js
const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }
const Test = {
template: '<div>Test : {{ nb }}<br><button @click="addOne" type="button">+1</button></div>',
props: {nb: Number},
methods: {
  addOne() {
    this.nb++
  }
}
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { name: 'test', path: '/test/:nb', component: Test, props: true }
  ]
})

new Vue({
 router,
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/">/home</router-link>
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'test', params: { nb: 42 }}">/test</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

> Note : This example show a "mutating a prop directly" warning, but it's just for the simplicity it's not related to the issue since I don't do that in my code.

#### In this example the update doesn't work :

```js
const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }
const Test = {
template: '<div>Test : {{ counter.value }}<br><button @click="addOne" type="button">+1</button></div>',
props: {counter: Object},
methods: {
  addOne() {
    this.counter.value++
    console.log('new value : ' + this.counter.value)
  }
}
}

class Counter {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value
  }
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    {
      name: 'test',
      path: '/test/:nb',
      props: (route) => ({counter: new Counter(route.params.nb)}),
      component: Test
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
 router,
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/">/home</router-link>
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'test', params: { nb: 42 }}">/test</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `counter` object won't be reactive, so property changes won't be detected. Passing an object as a prop does not add reactivity.

I've just changed one line in your example:

```js
props: (route) => ({counter: Vue.observable(new Counter(route.params.nb))}),
```

Passing the object to `Vue.observable` will apply the reactivity.

Note that 'applying reactivity' means rewriting all of the properties to use getters and setters. In the simple example presented here that just means the `value` property, which should be fine. Vue can only rewrite properties it can see, so any data hidden within closures would not be accessible.

```js
const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }
const Test = {
template: '<div>Test : {{ counter.value }}<br><button @click="addOne" type="button">+1</button></div>',
props: {counter: Object},
methods: {
  addOne() {
    this.counter.value++
    console.log('new value : ' + this.counter.value)
  }
}
}

class Counter {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value
  }
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    {
      name: 'test',
      path: '/test/:nb',
      props: (route) => ({counter: Vue.observable(new Counter(route.params.nb))}),
      component: Test
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
 router,
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/">/home</router-link>
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'test', params: { nb: 42 }}">/test</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Part of the reason why Vue does not automatically apply reactivity to objects passed as props is that the receiving component shouldn't be modifying the object anyway. It's a violation of one-way data flow. In this example you should probably be updating the route directly rather than modifying the `counter` object.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I couldn't find any documentation about this behaviour. For the one-way data flow, like I said in my post I did it in the example to keep it simple. But in my case the object is updated in background through IPC.